# VBA - Range("All cells but a few")

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear the contents of all cells on a worksheet apart from a specific range. I have tried to copy the range to the clipboard then to paste it back on again in the same place, however excel being the usual tricky beast - it doesn't want to play ball.

The range I would like to keep the same is AB1:AC5.

Any Suggestions Apprichiated...

(here is my code)

```
Sub Button21_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets(2)
.Range("AB1:AC5").Copy
.Cells.ClearContents
.Paste(Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("AB1"))
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an array instead:

```
Sub Button21_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim oldValues As Variant

With Worksheets(2)
    oldValues = .Range("AB1:AC5").Value
    .Cells.ClearContents
    .Range("AB1:AC5").Value = oldValues
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply - this works great! thankyou!

Comment: no worries, don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved the issue!